How to efficiently select the top N columns by grouping for each row of a pandas DataFrame?
Let's say that I have a pandas DataFrame representing the coolness score for each "contestant" of a hypothetical contest by date:
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

rng = np.random.default_rng()
dates = pd.date_range('2024-08-01', '2024-08-07')
contestants = ['Alligator', 'Beryl', 'Chupacabra', 'Dandelion', 'Eggplant', 'Feldspar']
coolness_score = pd.DataFrame(rng.random((len(dates), len(contestants))), index=dates, columns=contestants)

            Alligator     Beryl  Chupacabra  Dandelion  Eggplant  Feldspar
2024-08-01   0.213901  0.952705    0.801651   0.511080  0.662109  0.486296
2024-08-02   0.495700  0.660502    0.379900   0.778438  0.038616  0.214174
2024-08-03   0.639337  0.036226    0.811501   0.281915  0.101850  0.437146
2024-08-04   0.238590  0.686965    0.357087   0.810922  0.907803  0.370247
2024-08-05   0.712564  0.800191    0.040616   0.503644  0.354333  0.742269
2024-08-06   0.916343  0.299557    0.405399   0.851161  0.336570  0.246618
2024-08-07   0.047052  0.645420    0.823397   0.198483  0.368888  0.168188

In addition, each contestant is mapped to a particular category, and limits are imposed on each category:
category_mapping = {
    'Alligator': 'Animal',
    'Beryl': 'Mineral',
    'Chupacabra': 'Animal',
    'Dandelion': 'Vegetable',
    'Eggplant': 'Vegetable',
    'Feldspar': 'Mineral'
}

category_limits = {
    'Animal': 1,
    'Vegetable': 2,
    'Mineral': 1
}

How do I go about selecting which contestants yield the top scores for each category across each date? Specifically considering three scenarios:

The best single score from each category

The best N scores from each category, where N is consistent across all categories

The best scores from each category with limits defined by category_limits


Or, even better, how do I set the scores of the losers to zero?
Scenarios 1 and 2 are clearly subsets of Scenario 3 but I figured there might be some built-in functions that can yield efficiency gains here. If left to my own devices, I'd probably iterate by date, but this seems like it would be the absolute slowest possible approach. Thanks for your help.
Edit 1: In Scenario 3, I mean to apply category-specific limits to each date. So using the example posted above, that would be the top Animal, top two Vegetables, and top Mineral each date.
Edit 2: Amazing answers so far. I should add that I'm also looking for speed, and my actual application is on the order of 250 rows x 15000 columns, with about 175 different categories, and will be run many, many times as part of a Monte Carlo simulation. I'll be testing each solution when I have a clearer mind, but I welcome any discussion about performance at the intended scale. Thanks!

You can use mapping and groupby.rank, then a mask with where:
# names to categories
cat = coolness_score.columns.map(category_mapping)
# categories to limits
limit = cat.map(category_limits)

# rank per category
rank = coolness_score.T.groupby(cat).rank(method='dense', ascending=False).T
# identify top N per category per row
mask = rank.le(limit)

# mask losers
out = coolness_score.where(mask, 0)

Output:
            Alligator     Beryl  Chupacabra  Dandelion  Eggplant  Feldspar
2024-08-01   0.000000  0.878593    0.957980   0.887114  0.266656  0.000000
2024-08-02   0.000000  0.660319    0.737451   0.921197  0.446438  0.000000
2024-08-03   0.000000  0.000000    0.765396   0.334504  0.250021  0.736392
2024-08-04   0.000000  0.000000    0.990308   0.357501  0.124491  0.941783
2024-08-05   0.327078  0.000000    0.000000   0.309475  0.538202  0.952041
2024-08-06   0.533576  0.000000    0.000000   0.935781  0.587427  0.690166
2024-08-07   0.767592  0.000000    0.000000   0.222281  0.879662  0.821808

Intermediates:
# cat
Index(['Animal', 'Mineral', 'Animal', 'Vegetable', 'Vegetable', 'Mineral'], dtype='object')

# limit
Index([1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 1], dtype='int64')

# rank
            Alligator  Beryl  Chupacabra  Dandelion  Eggplant  Feldspar
2024-08-01        2.0    1.0         1.0        1.0       2.0       2.0
2024-08-02        2.0    1.0         1.0        1.0       2.0       2.0
2024-08-03        2.0    2.0         1.0        1.0       2.0       1.0
2024-08-04        2.0    2.0         1.0        1.0       2.0       1.0
2024-08-05        1.0    2.0         2.0        2.0       1.0       1.0
2024-08-06        1.0    2.0         2.0        1.0       2.0       1.0
2024-08-07        1.0    2.0         2.0        2.0       1.0       1.0

# mask
            Alligator  Beryl  Chupacabra  Dandelion  Eggplant  Feldspar
2024-08-01      False   True        True       True      True     False
2024-08-02      False   True        True       True      True     False
2024-08-03      False  False        True       True      True      True
2024-08-04      False  False        True       True      True      True
2024-08-05       True  False       False       True      True      True
2024-08-06       True  False       False       True      True      True
2024-08-07       True  False       False       True      True      True


Note: I'm not sure how the coolness score works, but you might want to use ascending=False in rank to rank the large scores first.

Thanks, I'm going to mark this as the accepted answer due to conciseness and flexibility. However, as I continue to work with my dataset I am seeing my needs change. I'm particularly intrigued by the use of idxmax put forth by @rezan21 for the case where you take the best score from each category, as it is significantly faster than a full sort and rank. I will post a second question with an updated ask and see if I can source efficient approaches from the community.

import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

rng = np.random.default_rng()
dates = pd.date_range('2024-08-01', '2024-08-07')
contestants = ['Alligator', 'Beryl', 'Chupacabra', 'Dandelion', 'Eggplant', 'Feldspar']
coolness_score = pd.DataFrame(rng.random((len(dates), len(contestants))), index=dates, columns=contestants)

## solution:
# melt dataframe(from wide to long data format)
df = coolness_score.reset_index().rename(columns={"index": "date"}).melt(id_vars="date", var_name="contestant", value_name="coolness_score")

# map contestant to category and insert category column after date column
category_mapping = {
    'Alligator': 'Animal',
    'Beryl': 'Mineral',
    'Chupacabra': 'Animal',
    'Dandelion': 'Vegetable',
    'Eggplant': 'Vegetable',
    'Feldspar': 'Mineral'
}
df.insert(1, "category", df["contestant"].map(category_mapping))

# sort by date and category for better readability
df = df.sort_values(by=["date", "category"], ignore_index=True)

# the id of the best single score from each category for each day
day_category_top = df.groupby(["date", "category"])[["coolness_score"]].idxmax().rename(columns={"coolness_score": "best_score_index"})

# 1. The best single score from each category
df.loc[day_category_top["best_score_index"]]

# 2. The best N scores from each category, where N is consistent across all categories
N = 3
df.groupby(["date", "category"]).apply(lambda g: list(g["coolness_score"].nlargest(N)))

this solution assumes on a given day, each contestant appears once.(i.e. one score per day per contestant), which is what your data suggests.
for the 3rd scenario, it wasn't clear if you mean to apply the limit on the total score of the category or not. if so:
# 3. The best scores from each category with limits defined by category_limits
category_limits = {
    'Animal': 1,
    'Vegetable': 2,
    'Mineral': 1
}
# sum of the scores for each category, but capped at limit
sum_score = df.groupby(["date", "category"])[["coolness_score"]].sum().reset_index()
sum_score["actual_score"] = sum_score.apply(lambda x: min(x["coolness_score"], category_limits[x["category"]]), axis=1)
sum_score

and you can apply similar login to 1 and 2 to actual_score.

Ah, thanks! I'll give your answer a better read once I get some sleep, but wanted to respond quickly -- in Scenario 3, I meant to apply category-specific limits to each row. So in my example, that would mean for each date, I'd want to take the top Animal, top two Vegetables, and top Mineral. I'll amend my original question to make this clearer.
